# Hover state not working after clicking

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, hover, contact-form

so I have this page https://tricote.net/contact/
Where you have few links on the left and when you click them, it launches your mail app and let you send emails to the shop.

However, after clicking one of them, clicked links hover state on turn off and rest of the links won't turn on the hover state....

Is there any way to fix this..?
Thank you for you time in advance...!

Comment: It looks like it has JavaScript event listeners on the click function, and it's not a simple hover thing.

Comment: The hover state will be turned off as the browser detects that the cursor is no longer hovering the box which is working as expected.
The problem here is you have JavaScript code that adds inline style to the boxes. You have to remove that as Aliester instructed so it can work properly. You can check this by running this code `$(".contactbox").each(function(i, e){$(e).css("background", "");});` in the browser console after you clicked on one of the box to visualize the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this is your problem code:

```
    $(".contactbox").each(function() {
        var e;
        return e = this,
        $(e).on("click", function() {
            var t, n;
            return t = $(".contactbox").index(e),
            $(".contactbox").css("background", "#fff"),
            $(e).css("background", "#648d85"),
            n = $(".contactbox").eq(t).data("label"),
            $("#contact_subject").val(n)
        })
    })
```

Essentially you are setting the background color using the "style" attribute of the HTML element when you use ".css".  This overrides anything set in the CSS file.  I believe this also overrides the "hover" styling.

So you will want to change these lines:

```
$(".contactbox").css("background", "#fff"),
$(e).css("background", "#648d85")
```

You could create an additional class that specifies that "active" element styling instead of using ".css".  This could look like this:

```
$(".contactbox").removeClass("activeElement");
$(e).addClass("activeElement");
```

This way you can control what overrides what through ordering in the CSS file or provide an additional css rule for the "activeElement" class hover behavior.

EDIT1:
Ok so from your comment is sounds like you don't really want to style the user's last selection.  So instead just remove these lines:

```
$(".contactbox").css("background", "#fff"),
$(e).css("background", "#648d85")
```

I had thought you wanted to indicate to the user what the last selection was.  It sounds like you don't want that so you don't need use the "removeClass"/"addClass" lines I included above.

Hopefully I am understanding what you want to do.  If not here is a list of possible states for these elements.  Please add a comment or update your question indicating how you want each state combination styled.  I numbered it so you can reference it by number

Current Possible States:

1. Item Selected / Not Hovering
2. Item Selected / Hovering
3. Item Not Selected / Not Hovering
4. Item Not Selected / Hovering

With the recommendations in this edit (State-1 === State-3) and (State-2 === State-4).

Comment: Thanks! Now other links can turn off hover state after one link has been clicked. However, after you click one link, that same link you clicked on won't turn off the hover state even if my mouse is removed from the link....

Is there anything else causing this to happen?

Comment: @HirohitoYamada  I am not sure I understand.  From your code currently when an item is selected it's background color is set to the same color as the hover style.  I assumed you intended this to indicate the active element.  If you can describe what style you want for:  "selected and not hovering", "selected and hovering", "not selected and not hovering", and "not selected and hovering" then I can update my answer.

Comment: Sorry for confusing comment.
So heres the problem I have left after applying your suggestion.

1:You click one, open mail app.
2:Cliecked links background, stays on hover and it wont go back to white background no matter what...

Comment: @HirohitoYamada  Ok updated my answer.  let me know if I am still misunderstanding what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you so much! great answer! Solved perfectly!

Comment: @HirohitoYamada  Happy to help.  Take care.